# Can I do Swipe Transition with CIImageAccumulator in IOS?

Tags: ios5, core-image

I have 2 images one is on top of another. the image on the top should disappear or appear if I roll iPad up/down. The effect should be like Swipe Transition effect.

To do this, if I redraw the top image every angle that the device is rolled, application is slow down and transition effect is not playing smoothly.

In the Core Image Programming Guide, I saw a topic for Imaging Dynamical Systems.

Is it useful for my situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `CIImageAccumulator` is not available in iOS 5 SDK (at least not in 5.1).
You can create your own CIFilter or use opengl shaders to make it faster.

Also, I think you don't need is to re-draw the image at *every* angle, people will barely notice it, you could draw every 5 or even 10 degrees according to your needs.